# Print the longest line of series of texts with number of characters

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am starting to learn python and gotten this far to code a program to allow user input a series of lines of text to then output the longest line's number of characters. Could you please tell me what I need to add to display the longest text itself with the number of characters?
thank you.

```
print('Please enter lines of text.')
print('Finish with a blank line.')
maxi = 0
text = '.'
while len(text) > 0:
    text = input()
    if len(text) > maxi:
        maxi = len(text)
if maxi == 0:
    print('No text entered.')
else:
    print('The longest line of text was ' + str(maxi) + ' characters long.')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to save the maximum length text like this:

```
print('Please enter lines of text.')
print('Finish with a blank line.')
maxi = 0
maxiText = ''
text = '.'
while len(text) > 0:
    text = input()
    if len(text) > maxi: 
        maxi = len(text)
        maxiText = text
if maxi == 0:
    print('No text entered.')
else:
    print('The longest line of text was ' + str(maxi) + ' characters long. The text is ' + maxiText)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by either introducing another variable to store the text of the longest line found, or replace the length in the `maxi` variable with the text of the line and use `len(maxi)` to compare lengths. While this choice may seem irrelevant in this scope, you can keep this in mind for larger-scale problems in the future, where the re-calculated function is more complex than `len()`.

**New variable:**

This saves a little bit of processing by storing the length of the current longest line in a separate variable. However, you manually have to keep them both in sync.

```
print('Please enter lines of text.')
print('Finish with a blank line.')
maxi = 0
text = '.'
maxline = ""
while len(text) > 0:
    text = input()
    if len(text) > maxi:
        maxi = len(text)
        maxline = text
if maxi == 0:
    print('No text entered.')
else:
    print('The longest line of text was ' + str(maxi) + ' characters long.')
    print(maxline)
```

**Only storing the text of the longest line:**

This way you always have to recalculate the current length of the longest line, but you are sure to always get the correct length.

```
print('Please enter lines of text.')
print('Finish with a blank line.')
maxi = ""
text = '.'
while len(text) > 0:
    text = input()
    if len(text) > len(maxi):
        maxi = text
if maxi == "":
    print('No text entered.')
else:
    print('The longest line of text was ' + str(len(maxi)) + ' characters long.')
    print(maxi)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to save the test when he is higher than your previous maxText.
And at the end you can now print it.